# Result of order by query showing wrong

Tags: php, mysql

I am calling on sql query with order by primary id.

```
eg. "select product_id from products where order by product_id DESC"
```

This query giving me all list of products, but not in desc order,
its giving me like
product_id
1033
599
587
167
1233
1224
like this
Whenever I use pagination its giving me larger number in second page call.
Can anyone tell me why this happening?

Comment: please post your original code. there is nothing wrong in what you are doin.

Comment: Is product_id a varchar or a number datatype? And please post the actual query (ie one that is valid SQL syntax)

Comment: product_id is primary key int

Comment: what is the condition?

Comment: If you want help with a query, it helps to see the query

Answer (score 0):

If you add a `WHERE` keyword, you have to follow it up with at least one criterion. Take it out and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

your query should be like this :   `select product_id from products  order by product_id DESC`

if you want to add some condition then you must specified that after `where column_name=criteria`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `where clause` you have to give at least condition to match.if you do not have any condition to match `do not use where clause`:

```
select product_id from products order by product_id DESC
```

if you want to use where clause do something like this:

```
 select product_id from products where column_name='value for condition' order by product_id DESC
```